# Displaying Image On Button Swift

Tags: xcode, button, swift, uiimage

I tried this code but I am getting errors. How could i put an Image in a button.

```
Button.setBackgroundImage("ImageName", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: What sort of class is `Button`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming what you have as `Button` is actually a `UIButton` instance, it isn't enough to just pass name for an image, you actually need to pass in an actual UIImage:

```
let image = UIImage.named("ImageName")
myButton.setBackgroundImage(image!, forState: .Normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of `UIImage` initialized with your image. Then use that as the image to use for your button

Answer (score 0):

Its also posible without writing a code. Just copy image into your project and do following steps. Then you can change size and position of your button with constrains.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The title of the question says you want an image on the button but you seem to use the background image in the code. Either way, both are easy features to achieve. Just write similar code as below

```
let newButton = UIButton(type: .custom)

newButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "ImageName"), forState: .normal)
```

Now if you want to set an Image on the button then you may use :

```
newButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "ImageName"), for: .normal)
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!!